# Learning arithmetic function with tensorflow multi-layer perceptron network

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

The network I am trying to build, using the tensorflow python library, looks like this:

[image: network]

A simple network with two nodes on the input layer, one on the output layer and two nodes on the hidden layer. Nodes `z1` and `z2` use the sigmoid activation function, and node `y` is just a linear combination of `z1` and `z2`, without an activation function. The loss function is the mean squared error.

The function I am trying to learn is:

`y = 0.26(x1^2 + x2^2) - 0.48*x1*x2` where `xi ∈ [-10,10]` for `i = 1,2`

Although it is non-linear, it's not a particularly complicated function, so it should be completely fine for this network to learn, given a training set of 100 samples generated using latin hypercube sampling on the domain - and in fact, I can do it with 3 lines of code in MATLAB:

```matlab
rng(0, 'twister');
x_train = (repmat(-10, 100, 1) + repmat(10, 100, 1)...
    .* lhsdesign(100, 2))';
y_train = 0.26 * (x_train(1, :).^2 + x_train(2, :).^2)...
    - 0.48 .* x_train(1, :) .* x_train(2, :);
x_test = (repmat(-10, 10, 1) + repmat(10, 10, 1)...
    .* lhsdesign(10, 2))';
y_test = 0.26 * (x_test(1, :).^2 + x_test(2, :).^2)...
    - 0.48 .* x_test(1,:) .* x_test(2,:);

net = feedforwardnet(2, 'trainlm');
trained_net = train(net, x_train, y_train);
y_pred = trained_net(x_test);
perform(trained_net,y_test,y_pred) % output 0.0222 with rng seed 0
```

Which gets me pretty accurate predictions (MSE of 0.0222 with 100 training samples and 10 test samples), and even more accurate if the number of samples is increased.

I am having trouble recreating these results using the tensorflow python library though. I have looked at a lot of examples online and read through the documentation for the library, but most of the examples that I can find are for building classifier networks, which is not what I am trying to do, and when I try to adapt the examples to my purpose, it doesn't work.

The code I have written so far is:

```
import numpy as np
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras import layers
import pyDOE as doe

np.random.seed(0)


def obj_fn(X):
    return np.array([0.26 * (X[:, 0] ** 2 + X[:, 1] ** 2)
                     - 0.48 * X[:, 0] * X[:, 1]]).T


def MSE(y_hat, y):
    return np.square(y_hat - y).mean()


x_train = -10 * np.ones((100, 2))\
    + 20 * np.ones((100, 2)) * doe.lhs(2, samples=100)
y_train = obj_fn(x_train)
x_test = -10 * np.ones((10, 2))\
    + 20 * np.ones((10, 2)) * doe.lhs(2, samples=10)
y_test = obj_fn(x_test)


model = keras.Sequential([
    keras.Input(shape=(2), name='input'),
    layers.Dense(2, activation='sigmoid', name='hidden'),
    layers.Dense(1, name='output'),
])

model.compile(
    optimizer='adam',  # Optimizer
    loss='mse',
)

history = model.fit(
    x_train,
    y_train,
    epochs=1000)

y_pred = model.predict(x_test)
MSE(y_pred,y_test)  # output average around 70-110 with rng seed 0
```

But when trained on 100 samples for 1000 epochs, and then tested on the test set of 10 samples, it only gets a mean squared error of 84.78, which is pretty terrible. I can get  much better results if I increase the size of the hidden layer, but this should be quite a simple problem for this network to solve (and indeed MATLAB did it with no issues), so I am clearly doing something wrong somewhere. Can someone please help me work out what it is?

Comment: Which hyperparameters did you use for your matlab network?

Comment: I have read about using `sigmoid` activations in hidden layers; i think it was in ancient history, and that they were extinct today. In any case, please post a [mre] (including the data generating code).

Comment: @AloneTogether - just the default ones that are used when you train with 'trainlm'

Comment: @desertnaut - yes, but I am just working with a very simple example, so that I can get my head around using the tensorflow library. It is a very basic function so the network should be able to easily learn it with 2 hidden nodes, even using the sigmoid function of the ancients. One advantage of using sigmoid is that it is easy to compute the network by hand if I need to. (I have updated the post with data generating code)

Comment: Where in the Matlab docs is it clarified that the activation here is the sigmoid?

Comment: @desertnaut - it doesn't, but that doesn't matter. I'm not trying to recreate the MATLAB results, the point of using that example was to show the problem can be solved easily in another context using 3 lines. If your argument is that the only reason my tensorflow network isn't working, is because it is not theoretically possible to learn this function using sigmoid nodes, then that is fine - I don't necessarily agree, but if I can make it work by changing the activation function only, then that would be a big help as well. I know I have done something wrong, and I just want to know what it is.

Comment: Have you tried `relu`?

Comment: @AloneTogether - I just tried then, its an improvement, but still gives an MSE of around 20-40. Are you saying that there is nothing obviously wrong with how I have set up the network and that it is probably just a matter of tweaking and tuning parameters?

Comment: It is an interesting observation in any case; and no, there is not anything wrong with your Keras model in principle.